# Elastic Search 7 - how to query against multiple options of a field order email has 1. customer email, 2.shipping email, 3.billing email

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing orders from a database. When searching for a customer I want to be able to provide something like the following in the query string:

```
email:tom@test.com
```

The problem I have is that my model has multiple emails against different related models. For example:

- order.customer.email
- order.shipping.email
- order.billing.email

I want to be able to combine all these into a single email field.

I have tried creating a new key on the order document root called email and filled it with a list, such as:

```
order
|- email: "tom@test.com,tom@test2.com,tomsCompany@test.com"
```

This does work, but it causes issues when returning the data in areas such as highlighting the results.

Is there a way I can do something like:

```
order
|- email
   |-tom@test.com
   |-tom@test2.com
   |-tomsCompany@test.com
```

Where I can still search for `email:tom@test.com` but instead of being returned with a hit of 
value of "tom@test.com,tom@test2.com,tomsCompany@test.com" I just get the one value "tom@test.com"

**EDIT**

An alternative would be to pre-process my query string before its submitted to ES so "email:tom@test.com" is changed to `(customer.email:tom@test.com OR billing.email:tom@test.com OR shipping.email:tom@test.com)` but that feels quite messy too and requires an extra processing step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are collating all the email ids into a single field and only want to return the exact hit, the only way to do that would be to make use of [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) datatype.

Basically every value in a `nested` datatype is a document in itself. ES *doesn't return* only a part of the field's value as the response for search queries.

The way they've designed `nested` datatype is that *every value in the list would be treated as a document*. Now when a user searches for that value, it has a way to mention in the response which inner document has had a hit.

Please see below sample mapping, the document, query and the response.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_nested_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "order":{
        "type": "nested",           <---- Note this
        "properties": {
          "email":{
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Document:

```
POST my_nested_index/_doc/1
{
  "order":[
    {
      "email": "tom@test.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "tom@test2.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "tomsCompany@test.com"
    }
    ]
}
```

### Nested Query:

```
POST my_nested_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {                      <---- Note this. Nested Query
            "path": "order",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "order.email": "tom@test.com"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {                <---- Inner hits field
              "_source": "order.email"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've made use of [`nested query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) in order to find the document you are looking for. Notice in the response that there is a separate section [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#nested-inner-hits) and it is this section, that would help you know that which document among the nested documents has been a hit.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 24,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.9808291,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_nested_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",                           <---- The original document 
        "_score" : 0.9808291,
        "_source" : {                          
          "order" : [
            {
              "email" : "tom@test.com"
            },
            {
              "email" : "tom@test2.com"
            },
            {
              "email" : "tomsCompany@test.com"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {                       <---- Inner hits
          "order" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 0.9808291,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "my_nested_index",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "order",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 0.9808291,
                  "_source" : {                <---- The Exact Hit.
                    "email" : "tom@test.com"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice the section where I've mentioned `inner_hits`. This is where it would tell you which document it has hit.

Hope this helps!